# How can I make a Tomb of the Mask type of movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to come up with an idea on how to make a Tomb of the Mask type of movement but so far all of my ideas have failed. Any ideas that I could try next?

Comment: We can't help unless you show what you've already tried.

Comment: Just as an idea I am giving..  you can may be try using 'AddForce' or velocity to accelerate the rigidbody and then update the velocity to 0 whenever it 'OnCollideEnters' or 'OnTriggerEnters' to any wall with a collider attached.